# Given an IP address, how do I find which GCP Compute Engine instance it belongs too?

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I got a security warning like:

```
Security vulnerability found in server running at 123.45.67.89.
```

I have lots of Google Cloud Platform projects, and lots of instances running in each project.  How do I find which Compute Engine instance this ip address belongs to?

Answer (score 5):

Use the gcloud commandline tool with a filter.

`gcloud compute instances list --filter="EXTERNAL_IP=123.45.67.89"`

edit: Missed the many projects requirements. Using bash:

```
project_names=( "project1" "project2" "project3" )
for i in ${project_names[@]}; do gcloud compute instances list --filter="EXTERNAL_IP=123.45.67.89" --project=$i; done;
```

Comment: This is a good command but will only list instances in the current project `gcloud config list project`.

Comment: I read https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters, but I couldn't find the list of topics that can be used in a filter.  Does such a list exist?

Comment: Updated to work with a bash array of project names. I'm not sure about a full list of filters, that might be resource dependant. Basically anything that shows up at the top level when using `gcloud compute instances list --format=json` is filterable.

Comment: I don't see EXTERNAL_IP listed (in lowercase or uppercase) when I run `gcloud compute instances list --format=json`.

Comment: I think there are some shortcuts, you can also use any property drilled down like. `--filter="networkInterfaces.accessConfigs.natIP=123.45.67.89"`
Resource list: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/resource-keys

Comment: Add this to your script: `for PROJECT in $(gcloud projects list --format='value(projectId)')
do

Answer (score 5):

so... if anyone else needs to do this and ends up here, like I did.  You can literally use the search bar at the top of the google cloud interface to search for an IP.

Answer (score 4):

This PowerShell script will do the job.  It uses [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/).

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Given an IP address, finds a GCP Compute instance with the ip address.
.EXAMPLE
    PS C:\> .\Get-GcpInstance.ps1 --IpAddress 1.2.3.4
.OUTPUTS
    The GCP instance information.
#>
Param(
    [string][Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $IpAddress
)

function Get-GcpInstance {
    param (
        [string][Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $IpAddress,
        [string[]][Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $ProjectIds
    )
    foreach ($projectId in $projectIds) {
        $instances = gcloud compute instances list -q --project=$projectId --format=json | ConvertFrom-Json
        foreach ($instance in $instances) {
            foreach ($networkInterface in $instance.networkInterfaces) {
                if ($networkInterface.networkIp -eq $IpAddress) {
                    return $instance                    
                }
                foreach ($accessConfig in $networkInterface.accessConfigs) {
                    if ($accessConfig.natIP -eq $IpAddress) {
                        return $instance
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-GcpInstance $IpAddress (gcloud projects list --format=json | ConvertFrom-Json).ProjectId
```

I posted a slightly more sophisticated version of the script here: https://github.com/SurferJeffAtGoogle/scratch/blob/master/FindIp/Get-GcpInstance.ps1
It's more sophisticated because it only examines projects that I own, and it displays a progress bar.

P.S.  Powershell runs on [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-6) and [Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-6) too!  I wrote this code on Linux.

Comment: Nice script. This is going into my toolbox.